# Trying to pass a two dimensional array to function but receiving the error C2466

Tags: c, vector

I've been trying to solve a problem that was passed by my teacher about vectors and pointer, but for some reason, I've been receiving the error "error C2466". I've also tried to copy the code from [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-2d-array-parameter-c/) website, but I receive the same error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int static MAX = 3;

void bigger(int A[MAX][MAX], int n){
    /*int *k, *Lin, *Col;
    for (int i=0; i<MAX; i++ )
        for (int j=0; j<MAX; j++ )
        {
            printf("%d",A[i][j]);
        }*/
}

int main() {
    int A[3][3],z=0;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++ )
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++ )
        {
            A[i][j] = z;
            z++;
        }
    bigger(A,3);
}
```

I'm learning C, so I'm sorry for any mistakes in my code

Comment: What is "error C2466"? How do you compile the code? Who gives you the error? Does it say anything else than "C2466"?

Comment: The linked page has `const int M = 3;`. Why did you change `const` to `static`?

Answer (score 3):

The below code does not use a constant sized type in `int A[MAX][MAX]`.  Variable length arrays (VLA) and friends were introduced in C99.

```
int static MAX = 3;
void bigger(int A[MAX][MAX], int n){
```

[error C2466](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2466?view=msvc-160) implies a MS C compiler.  MS C compilers are not yet C99 compliant, hence the error.

Use a modern C compiler or do not use a VLA.

---

Below is a sample VLA usage code compiled on Windows OS machine, but not with a MS C compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3

void bigger(int n, int A[n][n]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      printf("%d", A[i][j]);
    }
}

int main() {
  int A[N][N], z = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      A[i][j] = z;
      z++;
    }
  bigger(3, A);
}
```